# Other than by firing, are there any visual cues that a UAV has reloaded its hellfire missile?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

The UAV control screen has a lot of meaningless data and numbers on the screen, so it's hard to tell if any of that information is useful.  After I fire a hellfire missile, I can't figure out how to tell if the missile has reloaded yet.

Is there any way to tell if the UAV is reloaded other than by firing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there IS a visual cue! The red guidance square disappears. That means you can fire again.

There are also auditory cues.  The crew (not sure why it sounds as though there is a mortar crew, since it's a UAV, but anyway) let you know when you're ready to go again.